# What should I prefer to use widget or renderPartial in Yii's view?

Tags: yii

I am confused when I should use a custom widget or renderPartial in my view files. Sometimes I use widget and sometimes I use renderPartial.

Comment: do you need this specific view at a **lot** of places? does it need a model?

Comment: you can consider any case, it seems me both are same. So don't know which to prefer and where ?

Comment: i think pentium has answered your question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Widget**

You use **widget** when your application logic is defined in a separate **CLASS file** and the logic is somehow separated and standalone.

Widget's are chosen when the functionality is repeatedly used elsewhere, on lot of pages.

**renderPartial**

You use **renderPartial** for **VIEW files** that you want to embed into something bigger, or when you want to print something without using the application layouts.

renderPartial is chosen when all the variables it need to access are already prepared in the current action.

Comment: I understand that widget is better to use But what we do using widget we can achieve through renderPartial and also any partial files can be accessed through whole application.

Comment: Situation drives when you need to use widget or renderPartial. If you are going to use the same "block" elsewhere in the site, go with widget, and in every other situation go with renderPartial.

Comment: Your answer is good for me but render partial can be accessed anywhere. I can consider widget for standalone logic.

Comment: Certainly it can be, it's not something that you would describe as "private", but it's not advised to be accessed from other controllers than his folder defines (unwritten standard).

Answer (score 1):

**Widget**
You can use widget when your site has some common part like header and footer or sometime some kind filter which require on every page of site.

**renderPartial**
Take example of search form of yii crude which is called by using renderPartial because that serach form is changing according to requirement of pages.

Sorry for english.