# Yii - partials, clips or widget?

Tags: php, templates, yii

We have a controller that manages sales.
We need to display a snipped of those sales on a dashboard. No more logic is involved.

What should that snipped be ?
A clip ? A partial ? Or a Widget ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should prefer widget for this requirement. We had some discussion over widget & renderPartial here
[What should I prefer to use widget or renderPartial in Yii's view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345025/what-should-i-prefer-to-use-widget-or-renderpartial-in-yiis-view)

I hope you will get your answer.

Comment: Thanks for that link. Actually, and by reading the answer there, I must conclude that, since we are talking of something that will ONLY be a partial on a big dashboard view, and it would NOT be repeated over and over again across several pages, renderPartial seems to be the proper way.

Answer (score 2):

You're likely looking for a widget.

Clips are (I think, I've not really used them much) specialised widgets for replacing common content on a page with a more specific version on the page.

I'm not sure what you mean by partial but I'd guess a `renderPartial`? This could work, but it means you have to provide that partial view with the data it needs every time you use it.

Widgets can pull their own data from your sources, take parameters to change behaviour and be themed. They're completely reusable and you can place them in your layout, or in your case, the dashboard view.

There can be many small widgets on the page which can be responsible for their own data, or you can have a parent->child structure, so you call the parent widget with some parameters, this gathers up the required data and splits it among the "child" widgets for different methods of display (graphs, tables, comparisons etc.).

Comment: Paystey - thanks a lot for your answer. Actually, with your explanation I now get where should widgets be used and why their logic is so important and they are so "strong". Since I have a controller for sales on the application, I believe a renderPartial will suffice. If however, I need to create something else, more complex, I may use Widgets then. Thanks a lot.